# overwrite existing field pnp

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am using pnp to import my content types and columns etc. I used to have a lookup field but I am wanting to change it to a lookup multi. I have done all of this but when I run the script to import it all it says that the field exists and is of a different type so skips it. How do I tell it to overwrite this field? I have added `overwrite=true` to the field properties but that has not worked

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible through pnp. A workaround is to use a custom powershell script to set the field to multi.